# How do I split this time string into 2 in order to compare dates?

Tags: ios6

I have a web service which returns dates as strings. How do I process these strings to determine if a particular store is open at a given moment?

Conceptually:

If (storeObject.date > now) {
"Replace image with open image"

But the date string is returned as:

Monday thru friday = "7:00am - 6:00pm"

How do I split this string into "7:00am" and "6:00pm"?

Comment: You write software.  Probably some folks will suggest various parsing schemes to help things along, but they will only get you so far.  NSDateFormatter may be of assistance, but not much, relatively speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString` and `- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange` to extract '7:00am - 6:00pm'

Then `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator` will help you split that string.

All of these are NSString methods.